# How to use data from another object within an #each block in Handlebars/Mustache

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js, mustache

If I have a set of data called `products` and if want to render them on a view page I can do something like this:

```
<ul class="product_list">
  {{#each products}}
    <li>{{products.ProductTitle}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

But in that loop above, I want to include some other data like this:

```
<ul class="product_list">
  {{#each products}}
    <li>{{products.ProductTitle}}</li>
    <img src="{{appvar.CDN}}/img.jpg"/> // appvar is a different data object
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

At the moment, if I do as above, I get nothing back from `{{appvar.CDN}}`. No error, just nothing... so it ends up rendering like `<img src="/img.jpg"/>`

I can't see this particular scenario addressed in the handlebars.js documentation (I think a lot of stuff is undocumented! may have to look into vue.js for the server side).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the handlebars documenation for paths https://handlebarsjs.com/#paths. To access the `appvar` you might need to include `../` before your property name, so that handlebars will evaluate it against a parent context.

Comment: Thank you! That solved my problem :) While seeking an answer it seems that Vue.js has a client-side and server-side framework. I guess with handlebars.js its really only for server-side templates.